# 3D object in iOS application

Tags: ios, 3d, rotation, touch, xcode5.0.1

I have to implement a 3D object in my iOS application,which can be rotated and the touch on every part is to be detected.Means have get the position where the user touched.This 3D human body object is in one of my view controllers.I am very new to OpenGL and Unity3D.As a objective C coder,which is the simplest method to achieve this requirement.A smooth rotation and touch detection on the object is the requirement.Can anyone done this or have suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

realistically you will have to use a game engine.  So, realistically that's Unity3D.  It's that simple.

It's inconceivable you could build from scratch all the framework you would need, to do that, in iOS. (It could be, literally, 5 to 20 man-years of work!)

Download Unity and try to enjoy learning it.  To do what you describe in Unity would take, literally, maybe 5 to 10 minutes. 1, drop the files from your model makers in the folder.  2, add an "if touched" script.  3, add a "orbit camera" script.

the shitty **[answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com)** site will very easily give you everything you need, for example just search on "orbit script".

it's annoying to move from iOS to Unity, but at least you can just press one button and get android builds, for no extra effort!  :)  Cheers

---

Just to be perfectly clear, you realise that MAKING THE MODELS for 3D development is incredibly difficult and expensive. Model makers charge 10s of thousands to make the "cgi world around us".  of course, there are a huge number of free models etc.  Note too that **[mixamo.com](https://www.mixamo.com/)** is what runs the body-animation side of the entire 3D industry.

(In Unity once you do what you describe above, you can click one button and add some animations to your humanoid ... then it can dance, fire weapons, etc!)

---

Final note .. consider instead Unreal engine, which is more objective-C oriented.  But Unity has all the market, it's easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Will try learning Unity3D.

Comment: Good luck!  Maybe see you on the unity page :)

Comment: yeah..its entirely new for me..dont know wether it success or not.

Comment: It's always a pain in the ass learning a new platform.  fortunately now parse.com has a unity version so you're all set for that.  Good luck!

Comment: can you provide a link for studying unity 3D.I m not intended to study it in deep.Just for my requirement.Do u have any such tutorial links?

Comment: It couldn't be easier, go here http://unity3d.com/learn and start watching the videos.  there is an INCREDIBLE amount of videos, books, and tutorials around regarding unity since, it is easily the biggest platform now for making apps.  since the "angry birds" guys changed to unity the flood of unity development has only increased.  just search anywhere for a zillion beginners tutorials. hope it helps